# Visual studio 2019 forces x64 and changes project/solution files unasekd

Tags: visual-studio, cmake, visual-studio-2019

I have a cmake project (cmake 3.19.0-rc1) that I want to build using Visual Studio 2019 (Microsoft Visual Studio Community 2019 Version 16.7.6). There are no toolchain files in the project.
The solution and project files are created via

```
 cmake -G "Visual Studio 16 2019" -A Win32
```

The solution is created successfully with the `Win32` target platform. The first build works as expected.
However after that, Visual studio informs me that the project and solution file has changed outside of the IDE and that they need to be reloaded. After that the target platform is `x64`.

I can manually re-add the `Win32` target platform, but with every compilation, visual studio resets the target platform to `x64`.

How can I stop this behavior and just stick with the Win32 platform?

Comment: I think there is something strange in `CMakeLists.txt`. The question can't be answered as is.

Comment: You can find the CMakeLists.txt for this project [in this github repo](https://github.com/Laguna1989/JamTemplateCppSFML/blob/master/CMakeLists.txt). If required, I can also provide a minimum working example.

Comment: Try replacing `file(GLOB_RECURSE ...)` with explicit file list.

Comment: I do not want to use globbing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apparently it was a Visual Studio extension (Clang Power Tools) that decided it needs to edit the stamp files. This caused a recreation after the build process.
The problem was solved by deactivating and deinstalling the Clang Power Tools extension.